# Grails submitRemote 'undefined' error

Tags: ajax, forms, grails, submit

I want to use the grails submitRemote feature to update contents of my div with Ajax. I wanted to write a simple example but I have problems which I cannot resolve. Hope you can help.

My controller:

```
class ResultsController {
    def index (){
        render "new updated content";
    }

}
```

My .gsp view:

```
<g:submitToRemote  class="button" update="resultDiv" value="Search" action="index" controller='results'/>

//div to be updated
div id="resultDiv" style="width:400px; height:400px; border:2px solid red">
</div>
```

I recieve the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "Updater" of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install the jQuery plugin and then tell grails to use it. That was it :)